# Check if datareader is empty

Tags: c#, datareader

I'm constant receive the error:

> Additional information: Data is Null. This method or property cannot
>   be called on Null values.

When I try to receive information. How can I check if the datareader is empty.

for example this is my code:

```
 while (rd.Read())
            {
                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    foundInformation[0] = rd.GetString(0);
                    foundInformation[1] = rd.GetString(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    foundInformation[0] = "nvt";
                    foundInformation[1] = "nvt";
                }               
            }
```

How can I check if rd.GetString(0) is empty?

Thankyou.

Comment: You check for rows but GetString goes for a column...

Comment: there is the IsDBNull method in the data reader

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call IsDBNull before you call GetString.

```
if (!rd.IsDBNull(0))
{
  //...
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx